# Black result image problem on BMP image resize using PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script to re size image file as below;

```
$file = "test.bmp";
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
$thumbname = "thumb/".$file_name.".".$ext;
$maxh = 200;
$maxw = 200;
$quality = 100;
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($file);

  $src = imagecreatefromwbmp($file);
  $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($maxw,$maxh);
  imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,200,200,$width,$height);
  imagejpeg($tmp,$thumbname,$quality);
  imagedestroy($tmp);
```

The script is suppose to resize a Windows bitmap image to 200x200 thumbnail. But instead, I am getting a black 200x200 image. I am using PHP with Apache in Windows PC. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just check `$src` prior using it. Maybe it's `FALSE`?

Comment: @hakre, what should I Change / replace

Comment: Look for `if(!$im)` in the example code over there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php

Comment: anybody post a working example please.... :(

Comment: Check the return value after you called the function. If it returns false, then you know that the function failed. From the other comments I read that you use the wrong function to open the image. You could have known that by verifying the return value. I have not seen that, it was just a quick guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.bmp` and `wbmp` are **VERY**, *VERY* different file types.

Note the `content-type` headers:

```
Content-Type: image/x-xbitmap
Content-Type: image/vnd.wap.wbmp
```

Calling `imagecreatefromwbmp($file)` where `$file` is a `.bmp` will fail every time.

See [this thread](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=111205) for info on how to load a `.bmp` file.  It's not pretty.

Comment: hi @rockerest, i got ur info helpful.. but how can i solve my prob?? is there something else better for `$src`???

Comment: @blasteralfred it's not about the `$src`.  `imagecreatefromwbmp` is the wrong function for loading a `.bmp`.  They are two different formats.  You need to create a custom function called `imagecreatefrombmp` and make it's contents the same as the function given [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?p=590870&postcount=5). I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [PHP imagecopyresampled() docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php):

---

Note:

There is a problem due to palette image limitations (255+1 colors). Resampling or filtering an image commonly needs more colors than 255, a kind of approximation is used to calculate the new resampled pixel and its color. With a palette image we try to allocate a new color, if that failed, we choose the closest (in theory) computed color. This is not always the closest visual color. That may produce a weird result, like blank (or visually blank) images. To skip this problem, please use a truecolor image as a destination image, such as one created by imagecreatetruecolor().

---

To see if it's the case you can use [imageistruecolor()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.imageistruecolor.php) and copy the contents to a new truecolor image before "copyresampling" it:

```
if( !imageistruecolor($src) ){
    $newim = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
    imagecopy( $newim, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height );
    imagedestroy($src);
    $src = $newim;
}
```

Comment: Good info, but I strongly believe this doesn't address the actual problem.

Comment: I thought about that as well but was not able to gather the code. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new opensource project on Github that allows reading and saving of BMP files (and other file formats) in PHP.

The project is called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//Create New 'Thumbnail' Image
$newImageWidth   = 200;
$newImageHeight  = 200;
$newImage        = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth, $newImageHeight);
$newImageFile    = 'output.jpg';
$newImageQuality = 100;

//Load old Image(bmp, jpg, gif, png, etc)
$oldImageFile    = "test.jpg";

//Specific function
$oldImage        = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldImageFile);

//Non-Specific function
//$oldImageContent = file_get_contents($oldImageFile);
//$oldImage        = imagecreatefromstring($oldImageContent);

//Get old Image's details
$oldImageWidth   = imagesx($oldImage);
$oldImageHeight  = imagesy($oldImage);

//Copy to new Image
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $oldImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newImageWidth, $newImageHeight, $oldImageWidth, $oldImageHeight);

//Output to file
imagejpeg($newImage, $newImageFile, $newImageQuality);
```

Comment: This solution will work with any type of source image that gd supports.

Comment: GD however does not support BMP files. You'll need to convert them. ImageMagik or use a generic command line tool.

Comment: Also, this is nice when you want a quick solution to load any image that GD supports, but `file_get_contents` + `imagecreatefromstring` is horrendously slow compared to the specific functions for each filetype, and a switch isn't _that_ much more work :)  I had actual benchmarks a while ago, but I can't find them any more.  Still looking....

Comment: @rockerfest: I just benchmarked it using this... http://dpaste.com/554667 The results show no difference in using specific functions or using non-specific(createfromstring).

Comment: The image files first few bytes tell gd which image type it is. This is standard for almost all binary filetypes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Sean ha, no problem.  It happens all the time.  I think the benchmarks I saw were related to memory issues.  Using even a 1.4Mpx image made php's memory use jump astronomically, and things started getting very, very slow.  I have no proof, though :)